# How do determine the URL of a remote git repo?

Tags: git, workflow

I'm trying to add a git repo on a team mates computer as a remote on mine, but can't figure out the correct syntax for the part after `git remote add john`

I have the path to his sites folder and can clone, push and pull. I just can't figure out the remote add.

I'm on a Mac, he's on a PC. The path to his sites is mounted (I think that's the right word) so I can get it at /Volumes/Users/Public/Sites

Can anyone help?

I appreciate some people don't see this as something worthwhile, I've heard and seen the arguments on both sites, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was overthinking it. All I had to do was `git remote add john /Volumes/Users/Public/Sites/test`

I was trying to figure out the equivalent of git@github.com:User/repo.git and getting in a tangle.

Thanks for the answers folks, I appreciate it.

Comment: if you solve the problem with this idea, you should approve it

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
git remote -v
```

Lists all remotes and their names in your repository.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it `git config --get remote.origin.url`